# Items copied from CD as read only

Tags: snow-leopard

I have a CD that when the items are copied to the desktop (OS 10.6) the items are marked as read only. The CD is UDF formatted and I have read the following on another site:

> The Mac simply doesn't understand the UDF format which is widely used
>   by many Windows and Linux computers, along with various consumer DVD
>   burners, video cameras and other devices. OS X gets confused when
>   reading files, thinking they have read-only privileges or locked files
>   or different owners, depending on what software was used to write the
>   disc. Other systems don't suffer from this problem because they fully
>   implement the 13-year-old UDF standard, but OS X doesn't.

Is there any way to get copied items to inherit permission of the folder that they are being copied to? I don't want to have to modify permissions everytime files are copied.

Comment: I'm commenting rather than answering because this isn't a complete solution. You can use Automator to create a Folder Action that will act on any file added to a defined folder. Automator allows you to use shell scripts within workflows. You can create a shell script to change permissions that will be applied to any file copied into the folder (or folders) to which this Folder Action is attached.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to copy the files from the command line using `rsync`: It supports a flag `--chmod`, so you can say, e.g.,

```
rsync -a --chmod=u+w /Volumes/name-of-the-CD/ /wherever/
```

to turn on writable flag for the user (you). Beware, though, that `rsync` takes a while getting used to, especially when recursively copying directories. Whether or not you end the name of the source directory with a slash actually makes a difference …